# How do I disable predictive text for reCAPTCHA on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, recaptcha

I'm using reCAPTCHA on a sign-up form. On mobile devices it's annoying as the phone constantly suggests dictionary words while you're typing.

I know how to turn this off for normal input fields, and I could probably do it by running some javascript after it's rendered and adding attributes to the input field - but...surely this should be off by default (as it's useless 99% of the time), or at least easy to configure to an 'off' setting?

I can't find anything useful in the documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's an [easy way](http://davidwalsh.name/disable-autocorrect) to disable autocomplete, autocorrect, and autocapitalise on mobile devices. It comes in the form of 3 attributes that can be used on input fields:

```
<input type="text" autocorrect="off" />
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
<input type="text" autocapitalize="off" />
```

You can also disable spell-checking:

```
<input type="text" spellcheck="false" />
```

---

As far as I'm aware there is no native way to disable autocomplete built into reCAPTCHA. As you say, I can't find anything in the docs or anywhere else.

As you say though, it would be fairly trivial to run a script to set this automagically:
With jQuery:

```
$("input[type=text]").attr("autocomplete", "off");
```

Without jQuery (vanilla JS):

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]").setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
```